# Shell script to extract data from a list of files and saving it as a csv

Tags: shell, awk, grep, csv

I'm on CentOS. I have a list of files that I want to read, extract data from them and organize it as a csv file.

The log files text format is:

```
...
{"name":"test-api","hostname":"ci47","pid":3202,"level":30,"msg":"File: dsiManager, Method: getContract, End { userId: 'AFC5EH5PIHHLO4XS7SG',\n  clientId: '5003700557',\n  intent: 'YesIntent',\n }","time":"2019-01-21T12:23:10.323Z","v":0}
...
```

Output format must be:

```
clientId;intent;time;userId
5003700557;YesIntent;2019-01-21T12:23:10.323Z;AFC5EH5PIHHLO4XS7SG
```

What is the most simple way to get this task done? (awk, grep...)

Comment: Sorry I missed ''json alike'' in title. I corrected the title. Thx !

Comment: I just surprised you wanted _most simple way_ but accepted most complex way,  lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used awk command. my problem was that every line is different from others.. So I did not have an idea about column numbers; I resolved this by adding a test to find the correct line number to show. 
Here is my code :

```
awk ' 
BEGIN {
  # Set awk script delimiter
  FS=","; 
  # Set CSV file separator
  OFS=";"; 
  # Set header part in csv file
  print "Method; UserId; ClientId; intent; time"
  } 
  /'clientId'/ 
  { 
    i=1; 
    msg=""; 
    while(i<=NF) { 
      if ($i ~ /clientId/) { 
        # Cleaning column value :
        gsub(/\\n\s{1,}clientId:\s/, "",$i); 
        msg = msg $i ";"
      };  
      if ($i ~ /"time"/) { 
        # Cleaning column value :
        gsub(/"time":/, "",$i); 
        msg = msg $i ";"
      }; 
      if ($i ~ /intent/) { 
        # Cleaning column value :
        gsub(/\\n\s{1,}intent:\s{1,}/, "",$i); 
        msg = msg $i ";"
      }; 
      if ($i ~ /Method/) { 
        # Cleaning column value :
        gsub(/(^(.*?)|\s{1,})Method\s{1,}?:?\s{1,}/, "",$i); 
        gsub (/(\s{1,}\{\s{1,}userId.*)?/, "", $i);  
        msg = msg $i ";"
      }; 
      if ($i ~ /userId/) { 
        # Cleaning column value :
        gsub(/(^(.*?)|\s{1,})userId:\s/, "",$i); 
        msg = msg $i ";"
      }; 
      i++
    } print msg
  } 
END {
  print NR
} ' 

$(grep -l id *.log) >> output.csv
```

1. I used gsub() method to clean somme column values, because I had dirty old log files
2. $(grep -l id *.log) command is used to list all awk input log files

Answer (score 2):

To parse JSON-encoded data robustly, you will need a JSON codec. This pretty much means Perl or Python (or Ruby ...). Since I'm a Perl guy, here's a Perl solution.

First off a one-liner:

```
$ perl -MJSON -ne 'BEGIN { print("clientId;intent;time;userId\n"); } eval { my $obj = from_json($_); my $msg = $obj->{msg}; $msg =~ s/^.*{\s*|\s*,\s*}.*$//g; my %m = map { m/^([^:]*):\s*(.*)/; ($1, $2) } split(/,\s+/, $msg); print("$m{clientId};$m{intent};$obj->{time};$m{userId}\n"); }; warn($@) if ($@);' <x
clientId;intent;time;userId
5003700557;YesIntent;2019-01-21T12:23:10.323Z;AFC5EH5PIHHLO4XS7SG
```

Since that is a little excessive, even for Perl, here's a readable script as well:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use JSON;

print("clientId;intent;time;userId\n");
while (<>) {
    # Don't choke on malformed lines
    eval {
        my $obj = from_json($_);
        my $msg = $obj->{msg};
        $msg =~
            s/^.*{\s*    # Trim up to and including the leading '{'
            |
            \s*,\s*}.*$  # Trim trailing ',}'
            //gx;
        # Split $msg into key-value pairs
        my %m = map {
            m/^([^:]*)   # Stuff that isn't ':'
            :\s*         # Field separator
            (.*)         # Everything after the separator
            /x;
            ($1, $2)
        } split(/,\s+/, $msg);
        print("$m{clientId};$m{intent};$obj->{time};$m{userId}\n");
    };
    warn($@) if ($@);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
awk -F "['\"]" 'NF>=26{print $19","$21","$26","$17}' file.csv


5003700557,YesIntent,2019-01-21T12:23:10.323Z,AFC5EH5PIHHLO4XS7SG
```

- `['\"]` to have both single and double quote as delimiters.
- `NF>=26` just to check the line has more than or equal to 26 fields.